# All ring homomorphisms from $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ to $\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I understand that the homomorhpism $\phi: \mathbb{Z}[X] \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ has to have a property that $\phi(1) = 1$. But how do I proceed with that to count all homomorphisms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that every such homomorphism is completely determined by the value of $\phi(x)$. Indeed, since $\phi(1)=1$ it easily follows by induction that $\phi(n)=n$ for all $n\in\mathbb{Z}$. And then:

$\phi(\sum_{i=0}^m a_ix^i)=\sum_{i=0}^m \phi(a_i)\phi(x^i)=\sum_{i=0}^m a_i[\phi(x)]^i$

So this shows that every homomorphism must have the form $\phi(\sum_{i=0}^m a_ix^i)=\sum_{i=0}^m a_ib^i$ for some $b\in\mathbb{Z}$. What is left to show is that for every $b$ this is indeed a homomorphism. This is really easy, so I'll leave it to you. So this gives you all the homomorphisms.

Comment: If $\phi(n) = n$ for all $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ then isn't it the case that $\phi(x)^i = x^i$?

Comment: @Naah No, because $x$ is not in $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: So what does it mean to write $\phi(x)$? Can I choose some arbitrary element of $\mathbb{Z}$ as $\phi(x)$?

Comment: @Naah What I'm saying is that if $\phi$ is a homomorphism then it is completely determined by the value $\phi(x)$. If you know what is $\phi(x)$ then you know what is $\phi$ in general. This means that for every $b\in\mathbb{Z}$ there is at most one homomorphism $\phi:\mathbb{Z}[x]\to\mathbb{Z}$ such that $\phi(x)=b$. So the part I left for you to check is that actually, for every $b\in\mathbb{Z}$ there is exactly one such homomorphism. This is easy, this homomorphism is just defined by $\phi(\sum_{i=0}^m a_ix^i)=\sum_{i=0}^m a_ib^i$.

Answer (score 0):

By virtue of the universal property of polynomial algebras, given a commutative ring $A$ and a associative & unitary $A$-algebra $E$, there is a canonical bijection between the set of (unitary) $A$-algebra morphisms from $A[X]$ to $E$ and the (support) set $E$ itself.

More generally, given a family $X$ of indeterminates indexed by $I$, there is a canonical bijection:
$$\mathrm{Hom}_{\operatorname{\mathit{A}-\mathbf{Alg_1}}}(A[X], E) \to \mathrm{Hom}_{\mathbf{Ens}}(I, E)$$
between the set of all (unitary) $A$-algebra morphisms from $A[X]\colon=A[X_i]_{i \in I}$ to $E$ and the set of all maps from $I$ to $E$.

It thus follows that in terms of cardinalities you have $\left|\mathrm{Hom}_{\operatorname{\mathit{A}-\mathbf{Alg_1}}}(A[X], E)\right|=|E|^{|I|}$. In the case of just one indeterminate - when $I$ is a singleton - this relation takes the simpler form $\left|\mathrm{Hom}_{\operatorname{\mathit{A}-\mathbf{Alg_1}}}(A[X], E)\right|=|E|$.

In your particular case $A=E=\mathbb{Z}$, hence $\left|\mathrm{Hom}_{\operatorname{\mathbb{Z}-\mathbf{Alg_1}}}(\mathbb{Z}[X], \mathbb{Z})\right|=|\mathbb{Z}|=\aleph_0$.